# How to show indicator inside select dropdown menu with Angular JS?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using bootstrap and bootstrap-select directive for AngularJS. And I want to do something similar to this http://cl.ly/image/301L0B2X2b0r.

Problem is I have no idea how to customize select template if we are using ng-option?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this way:

**Here is the fist:**

```
<select ng-options="i in items"></select>
```

**You can also do it this way ( not the ng-option way ):**

```
<select>
   <option ng-repeat='i in items'><option>
<select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be best to handle this outside of an actual `<select>` tag. Styling this tag is very inconsistent across browsers. Perhaps treat this as a bootstrap dropdown menu? You can create your own directive that wraps the dropdown menu so you can track the state of the model for your custom select control. You can then use ng-repeat on your list item tags and style them as you see fit!